# ImportError: no module named wrapper_util

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-sdk, dev-appserver

I am trying to test an a web app using google cloud sdk with python 2.7.
However, I get the error:

```
 "C:\Users\Public\My_Project>dev_appserver.py app.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 31, in <module>
    import wrapper_util
ImportError: No module named wrapper_util" when i run the 'dev_appserver.py app.yaml'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Google Cloud SDK components for Python may not be updated and does not yet include the module in the error. You can update them by running either of the following:

- `gcloud components update` 
  updates all components for the SDK
- `gcloud components install app-engine-python app-engine-python-extras` will install Python-specific components but will show `All components are up to date.` if you are using the latest version.